# How to prevent connected ends in geom_path line

Tags: r, ggmap

I am using Google Maps API and I have two questions:

1. How to have extra land space on right and left of the map?
2. How to not have line ends connected?

Here is an example of a map:
[image: Map]

Comment: to clarify the first question, I want to my base map starting from middle of Indian Ocean to Japan. But I don't want to have extra land area on top and bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the picture, I'm presuming you are using ggmap. The way to control the aspect ratio of the map is to use the `get_googlemap` function and specify the size:

```
map <- get_googlemap('china', zoom = 10, size = c(500, 200), scale = 2)
```

Comment: Did it at least give you a non square map?

Comment: Yes, it was non square but the locations were off. No use for me. I don't know what I did wrong. There is little for mistakes in this short lines of codes. Any idea?

Comment: Well I just gave you an example, you'll need to reset the actual location for the one you are using. That's why it's a good idea to provide code.